Can a triple product of characters be irreducible?
Note that every character of degree $ 1 $ is irreducible. And the product of any irreducible character with a degree $ 1 $ character is again irreducible. So any product of three degree $ 1 $ characters is irreducible. And if you start with a product of two characters of degree $ >1 $ that happens to be irreducible (see my question How often is a tensor product of two irreps of a finite group still irreducible?) and take a product with a third character of degree $ 1 $, then the triple product will still be irreducible.
But what if all three characters have degree $ >1 $? In other words, is it possible for a product of three characters, all of degree $ >1 $, to be irreducible?
Note that if $ \chi $ has degree $ >1 $ then $ \chi^2 $ is never irreducible. So for a triple product of characters to be irreducible the characters must at least be distinct.
Is this possible? Can a triple product of degree $ >1 $ characters every be irreducible?

@coiso ya definitely some missing words there, just put in a little edit should be fixed now

Take three non-abelian finite groups $G_1, G_2, G_3$ (we can even have $G_1=G_2=G_3$). Then consider $G=G_1 \times G_2 \times G_3$. For each $i=1,2,3$, take an irreducible representation $V_i$ of degree $>1$. Now consider the three irreducible representations of $G$ given by
$V_1 \boxtimes 1 \boxtimes 1, 1 \boxtimes V_2 \boxtimes 1, 1 \boxtimes 1 \boxtimes V_3$
We have $(V_1 \boxtimes 1 \boxtimes 1) \otimes (1 \boxtimes V_2 \boxtimes 1) \otimes (1 \boxtimes 1 \boxtimes V_3) \cong (V_1 \boxtimes V_2 \boxtimes V_3)$, which is irreducible.
If we take a direct product of $n$ non-abelian groups, an analogous construction gives an example of $n$ irreducible representations whose tensor product is irreducible.

What is the meaning of the symbol $ \boxtimes $? I have not seen it before

@IanGershonTeixeira From context, it's the tensor product, but for building a $G_1\times G_2$-rep out of a $G_1$-rep and a $G_2$-rep, rather than putting two $G$-reps together for another $G$-rep.

Ah ok so the fact being used here is that if $ \rho_1: G_1 \to GL(V_1) $ and $ \rho_2: G_2 \to GL(V_2) $ are both irreducible then this new thing $ \rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2: G_1 \times G_2 \to GL(V_1 \otimes V_2) $ acting by $ \rho_1(g_1) \otimes \rho_2(g_2) $ is an irreducible representation of $ G_1 \times G_2 $. Here $ \otimes $ is the standard tensor product of vectors space and tensor product of linear operators. While the box product $ \boxtimes $ is a novel operation that takes in representations of different groups and spits out a representation of their direct product

Is there any easy way to see that the box product of two irreps is again an irrep? It is clear to me that $ \rho_1 \boxtimes 1 \boxtimes 1 , 1 \boxtimes \rho_2 \boxtimes 1, 1 \boxtimes 1 \boxtimes \rho_3 $ are all irreducible, and moreover that $ (\rho_1 \boxtimes 1 \boxtimes 1) \otimes (1 \boxtimes \rho_2 \boxtimes 1) \otimes (1 \boxtimes 1 \boxtimes \rho_3)= \rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2 \boxtimes \rho_3 $. But I am still trying to think of an easy way to see that $ \rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2 \boxtimes \rho_3 $ is guaranteed to be irreducible (assuming $ \rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_3 $ are irreps).

@IanGershonTeixeira You said $\rho_1\boxtimes\rho_2$ is a $G_1\times G_2$-irrep if $\rho_1$ is a $G_1$-irrep and $\rho_2$ a $G_2$-irrep. Just extend this to three irreps, think of $(\rho_1\boxtimes\rho_2)\boxtimes\rho_3$ as a $(G_1\times G_2)\times G_3$-irrep.

@coiso ya what I mean is that's clearly the claim Lukas Heger is intending to use here, but I'm still asking for help understanding why that claim ( $ \rho_1 $ and $ \rho_2 $ irreducible implies $ \rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2 $ irreducible) is true. I of course agree with you that if the claim is true for a product of two then it is also true for an n-fold product.

@IanGershonTeixeira Ah, I see. It is a standard fact in rep thry texts. You can prove it using character theory (just calculate $\langle \chi,\chi\rangle$). You can probably prove it w/o character theory by combining Jacobson density theorem and Burnside's irreducibility criterion (I didn't check though).

ah I see I was missing the character formula  $$\langle \chi_1 \boxtimes \chi_2, \psi_1 \boxtimes \psi_2 \rangle_{G \times H} = \langle \chi_1, \psi_1 \rangle_G \langle \chi_2, \psi_2 \rangle_H$$ given here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5013555/724711 by Qiaochu Yuan

To take it to another extreme: if $\chi \in Irr(G)$ is a non-linear complex character of the finite group $G$, there are of course plenty of cases where $\chi^3$ is always reducible. Take $\chi$ for example to be the irreducible character of largest degree. But something more general is true.

Proposition Let $G$ be a finite group and $\chi \in Irr(G)$ a non-linear irreducible character. Then $\chi^n$ is reducible for all integers $n \geq 2$.
Proof Let $n \geq 2$ and assume that $\chi^n \in Irr(G)$, then of course $\chi^2 \in Irr(G)$. But $1 = [\chi^2, \chi^2] = [\chi\overline{\chi}, \chi\overline{\chi}]$, whence $\chi\overline{\chi} \in Irr(G)$. However, $[\chi\overline{\chi},1_G]=[\chi,\chi]=1$, that is, $1_G$ is always an irreducible constituent of $\chi\overline{\chi}$. We conclude that $\chi\overline{\chi}=1_G$, implying $\chi(1)=1$, a contradiction. $\square$

If $G=Q$ the quaternion group of order $8$ and $\chi \in Irr(G)$, with $\chi(1)=2$, then $\chi^3=4\chi$. Hence a related and interesting question could be to classify all groups that have an irreducible character $\chi$ with $\chi$ being the only constituent of $\chi^3$. For starters, if such a $\chi$ is faithful, then $G$ must be of central type and hence solvable by a famous theorem of R. Howlett and M.I. Isaacs (1982) (in fact one of the first applications of the Classification of all Finite Simple Groups). A group is said to be of central type if it has a $\chi \in Irr(G)$, such that $|G:Z(G)|=\chi(1)^2$ (or equivalently: $\chi$ vanishes off $Z(G))$.

Proposition Let $\chi \in Irr(G)$ be non-linear such that it is the only irreducible constituent of $\chi^3$. If $\chi$ is faithful, then $G$ is solvable.

Proof We have $\chi^3=k\chi$ for som positive integer $k$, and  applying the formula to $g=1$, the identity of $G$, we see that $k=\chi(1)^2$. Now take an arbitrary $g \in G$, then either $\chi(g)=0$ or $\chi(g) \neq 0$. In the latter case it follows from the formula that $(\chi(g)-\chi(1)(\chi(g)+\chi(1))=0$, whence $\chi(g)=\pm \chi(1)$. Hence $|\chi(g)|=\chi(1)$, so $g \in Z(\chi)$. If $\chi$ is faithful this implies that $g \in Z(G)$. Now since $\chi$ is irreducible, we have
$$|G|=\sum_{g \in G}|\chi(g)|^2=\sum_{g \in Z(G)}\chi(1)^2=|Z(G)|\chi(1)^2.$$
This yields $|G:Z(G)|=\chi(1)^2$, so $G$ is of central type and hence solvable. $\square$

For higher powers and related results, see also Harvey Blau, David Chillag, On powers of characters and powers of conjugacy classes of a finite group, Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 98 (1986), 7-10.

In a similar vein, there is interesting research on how the character $|\chi|^2=\chi\overline{\chi}$ would look like. See also Edith Adan-Bante, Products of characters with few irreducible constituents, J. Algebra 311 (2007), 38–68, and Lisa R. Hendrixson, Mark L. Lewis, Products of Irreducible Characters Having Complex-Valued Constituents, Advances in Group Theory and Applications, 4 (2017), 3-28.
